# How do I disable APC caching just changing any Drupal setting?

Tags: 8, caching

Is it possible to disable APC caching completely in Drupal 8 without modifying the php.ini settings (i.e. only by modifying the Drupal settings)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple settings necessary to do so:

in active settings.php:

```
/**
 * Class Loader.
 *
 * If the APC extension is detected, the Symfony APC class loader is used for
 * performance reasons. Detection can be prevented by setting
 * class_loader_auto_detect to false, as in the example below.
 */
$settings['class_loader_auto_detect'] = FALSE;

// Default cache backend.
$settings['cache']['default'] = 'cache.backend.database'; // or any other alternative cache backend
```

After looking at Berdirs comment and diving further into code and looking at more usages of apcu within Drupal it appears to be pretty much impossible to catch every usage / and even if you manage to find all of them - disabling at some points is not possible (e.g. no configuration options present).

Comment: The default isn't going to help you, you need to specifically change each f the fast chained bin, which by default are discovery, config and bootstrap. The default worked by accident before Drupal 8.2, but that was considered a bug and changed. Plus, there are a few things more, for example there is file caching for some yaml files based on Apcu